# MySql: REPLACE INTO with number=number+1

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, addition

I would like do something like this in one only query.

```
REPLACE INTO table ( id, number ) VALUES ( 'test', number=number+5 )
```

What I want is (the first time!) insert the row and set the number 5. 
the other times (if already exist) add 5 at the number.

Is it possible? I can't find nothing on line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just be sure that `ID` is unique. Use **[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)** Syntax

```
INSERT INTO tableName (id, number)
VALUES ('test', 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
number = number + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `id` is a proper key (e.g. primary key):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id, number)
VALUES ('test', 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number=number+VALUES(number)
```